# Strange error when turning a server response from the chrome.sockets.tcp api from an ArrayBuffer into a string

Tags: javascript, sockets, google-chrome, irc, google-chrome-app

I'm creating a chrome (packaged) app that would work with the irc protocol. So, here's what my listener looks like:

```
chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceive.addListener(function(info){
    console.log("received data");
    info.data = ab2str(info.data);
    console.log(info);
})
```

`ab2str` should convert ArrayBuffers to strings. I've copied it from html5rocks:

```
function ab2str(buf) {
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf));
}
```

But connect to `irc.freenode.net` on port 8002, I get weird strings of characters in the log, and on some occasions, I get the following error:

```
Error in event handler for sockets.tcp.onReceive: RangeError: bofyshould be a multiple ofe
at new Uint16Array (native)
at ab2str (chrome-extension://jkmacdefiplofpdmgimbaobepnigcchm/js/protocol.js:80:41)
at chrome-extension://jkmacdefiplofpdmgimbaobepnigcchm/js/protocol.js:73:15
...
```

Most of the stack trace looks like internal chrome code, so I left it out.

What am I doing wrong? Should I not listen for any data before sending the USER and NICK messages?

I've made sure that I'm connecting to freenode on a port that doesn't require ssl, as described in [this page about freenode's servers](http://freenode.net/irc_servers.shtml)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IRC is an ascii protocol, so I should interpret single bytes as characters, which I can do by replacing `Uint16Array` with `Uint8Array`